# rename feature layer fields

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

Guys and gals could you please provide me with a sample code as to how to rename a field name in a Feature Layer or Table.  I've been trying to use the **FieldInfo** object to do so over the last couple of days but it's not happening for me.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: arcgis and I attempting to use FieldInfo via arcpy.

Comment: Could you post a Python code snippet illustrating where you are stuck, please?  Are you trying to rename in an underlying feature class or table; or to rename in the corresponding feature layer or table view?

Comment: @ PolyGeo I am attempting to use this string 'fieldinfo.setFieldName(0,'FID')' in a for loop in order to simply rename an existing field name via Python.

Answer (score 3):

What this example code does is to add two **NEW fields** ("NAME_CITY"; "NAME_REGION") into your fieldinfo with desired new field names instead of just renaming the **ORIGINAL field** ("NAME_1"; "RegionNames").

After you renamed your fields you need to copy your table view/feature layer into a new table/feature class and that will be your output with renamed fields in it.

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

inputFeatureClass=r"C:/Desktop/Cities/Cities.gdb/USA_Cities"

#get fields from your input feature class
fields= arcpy.ListFields(inputFeatureClass)

# Create a fieldinfo objects
fieldinfo = arcpy.FieldInfo()

# Iterate through the fields and set them to fieldinfo
for field in fields:
    if field.name == "NAME_1":
        fieldinfo.addField(field.name, "NAME_CITY", "VISIBLE", "")
    elif field.name == "RegionNames": 
        fieldinfo.addField(field.name, "NAME_REGION", "VISIBLE", "")

# The created table view will have fields as set in fieldinfo objects
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(inputFeatureClass, "temp_Table_View", "", "", fieldinfo)

# Write the table view to a new table
arcpy.CopyRows_management("temp_Table_View", "C:/Desktop/Cities/Cities.gdb/City_Table")
```

Comment: instead of using fieldinfo.addField() should I use fieldinfo.setFieldName (index, field_name) to rename the field I'd like or should I use fieldinfo.setNewName?

Comment: Instead of adding a field I'd rather just rename it by using the methond in the comment above this one.

Comment: Just posted another answer which should give you what you want, thanks.

Comment: I tried this code for renaming feature class field name, but it did not work for me. Can you give me any other pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay. I just modified the python script and it is now using the "setNewName" method to rename a existing field instead of adding a new field.

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

inputFeatureClass=r"C:/Desktop/Cities/Cities.gdb/USA_Cities"
layer = "temp_layer"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inputFeatureClass, layer)
desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)

# If a feature layer, continue
if desc.dataType == "FeatureLayer":
    fieldInfo = desc.fieldInfo
    index = 0
    # Use the count property to iterate through all the fields    
    while index < fieldInfo.count:
        if fieldInfo.getFieldName(index)=="NAME_1":
            fieldInfo.setNewName(index, "NAME_CITY")

        elif fieldInfo.getFieldName(index)=="RegionNames":
            fieldInfo.setNewName(index, "NAME_REGION")
        index += 1

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("temp_layer","cities_lyr", "", "", fieldInfo)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("cities_lyr", "C:/Desktop/Cities/Cities.gdb/City_Renamed")
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Please let me know if you have any questions regarding the code above.

Thanks,

Jinnan

Comment: I've tried you modified code but it does not work work for me.   Your code looks right and as a matter of fact when I run it I do not get an error from the IDE.  I will continue to try you method, I sure the lies on my end.